# Using FireFeed example made by Firebase but can't get it working

Tags: javascript, firebase

This is code I clone https://github.com/firebase/firefeed
I haven't modified at all besides changing the demo firebase database to my firebase database and updating some of the "//" links so that they say https://.

I'm getting this error when I try to login with Facebook.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

When I look at Chrome Dev Tools the error is in obfuscated code so it's hard to understand what's going on. I can't figure out what function called the function in the obfuscated code.

This person had the same issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/firefeed/firebase-talk/ws4CaMi33PM/Ti00_qWVjOgJ

However I am running the app on a server and it's still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realized the problem. I needed to setup facebook authentication and get a secret and facebook id.

Edit: If it's still not working for you make sure you've updated your Firefeed link e.g.

this._firefeed = new Firefeed("https://YourFirebaseAppNameHere.firebaseio.com/");

as well as updated index.html links so that they say

"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com  ...."

instead of

"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com ..."

Comment: But you changed your firefeed clone to point to your own firebase database, right? Otherwise I'd have expected it to work without you having to setup FB authentication. If so, you should probably update your question to say so, just to be clear for anyone running in to the same problem.